# Problem importing Java classes in groovy files Java 11

Tags: java, maven, groovy, pom.xml, java-11

I've been trying to move an application to Java 11. This applications has multiple modules that use a common pom. After refactoring the main pom.xml to Java 11 I haven't been able to import Java classes correctly from Groovy classes and I keep getting this error from mvn clean compile "Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.: InvocationTargetException: startup failed:". Here's my pom file configuration.

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                        <goal>addSources</goal>
                        <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                        <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                        <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        <goal>removeStubs</goal>
                        <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>clean</id>
                    <phase>pre-site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>instrument</id>
                    <phase>site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>cobertura</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/groovy</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/test/groovy</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

What am I doing wrong?